# fluentd tcp input plugin not working

Tags: rsyslog, fluentd

When I running a fluentd td-agent to read the data from the tcp port 514 using **tcp plugin** but I find the error as,

```
   2015-05-25 15:32:18 +0000 [info]: adding match pattern="tcp.events" type="stdout"
   2015-05-25 15:32:18 +0000 [info]: adding source type="tcp"
   2015-05-25 15:32:18 +0000 [error]: unexpected error  error_class=Errno::EACCES error=#<Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - bind(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 514>
```

When I try to read the data from TCP port I find the data as

```
   nc -l 514
  <30>May 25 21:15:11 5gws056 docker/34cead996122[1865]: Hello Mon May 25 15:45:11 UTC 2015
  <30>May 25 21:15:12 5gws056 docker/34cead996122[1865]: Hello Mon May 25 15:45:12 UTC 2015
  <30>May 25 21:15:13 5gws056 docker/34cead996122[1865]: Hello Mon May 25 15:45:13 UTC 2015
  <30>May 25 21:15:14 5gws056 docker/34cead996122[1865]: Hello Mon May 25 15:45:14 UTC 2015
  <30>May 25 21:15:15 5gws056 docker/34cead996122[1865]: Hello Mon May 25 15:45:15 UTC 2015
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Any port number under 1024 requires root permission. It's called privileged ports. Could you try with bigger port number?